# show my components in ngb-tab with onclick menu items

Tags: angular

I have menu items like home, accounts, about and some more. which all contains data grids. and i am getting data from rest apis.

My Job is when user clicks on a menu item need to show that in tab
and my component having child components from which I am getting some filter conditions on which basis I am loading the data on the ag-grid..

Problem- 
1- sometimes same data loading in two tabs.
2- BehaviorSubject subscription is returning data of previous subscription.
3- this.router.navigate([path]) redirecting but showing a blank page. If I refresh that page then it loads the content.

> html-

This text is showing looping through the tab array and display the tab component

```
<ngb-tabset [destroyOnHide]="false" #tabs="ngbTabset" [justify]="currentJustify" [activeId]="selectedTab" 
                            (tabChange)="selectedTab = $event.nextId"> 
                                <ngb-tab  *ngFor="let tab of compTabs;let index=index" id= {{tab?.label}}>
                                <ng-template ngbTabTitle>{{tab?.label | titlecase}} 
                                    <i class="fa fa-times remove-tab" aria-hidden="true" (click) = "removeTab(index, $event)"></i> 
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                                    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="tab?.component">
                                    </ng-container>
                                </ng-template>
                                </ngb-tab>
                            </ngb-tabset>


    <ngb-tabset [destroyOnHide]="false" #tabs="ngbTabset" [justify]="currentJustify" [activeId]="selectedTab" 
                            (tabChange)="selectedTab = $event.nextId"> 
                                <ngb-tab  *ngFor="let tab of compTabs;let index=index" id= {{tab?.label}}>
                                <ng-template ngbTabTitle>{{tab?.label | titlecase}} 
                                    <i class="fa fa-times remove-tab" aria-hidden="true" (click) = "removeTab(index, $event)"></i> 
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                                    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="tab?.component">
                                    </ng-container>
                                </ng-template>
                                </ngb-tab>
                            </ngb-tabset>
```

---

```
component.ts-- for pushing the tab into the tab array
<pre>
    if (!tabContains) {                      
         this.compTabs.push(newTab);
         this.selectedTab = newTab.label    
         this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
      }
    }
```

except - it load proper data

I am not getting any proper reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `tab?` you must use `'tab'`.

```
  <ngb-tabset [destroyOnHide]="false" #tabs="ngbTabset" [justify]="currentJustify" [activeId]="selectedTab" 
                            (tabChange)="selectedTab = $event.nextId"> 
                                <ngb-tab  *ngFor="let tab of compTabs;let index=index" id= {{tab?.label}}>
                                <ng-template ngbTabTitle>{{tab.label | titlecase}} 
                                    <i class="fa fa-times remove-tab" aria-hidden="true" (click) = "removeTab(index, $event)"></i> 
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                                    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="tab.component">
                                    </ng-container>
                                </ng-template>
                                </ngb-tab>
                            </ngb-tabset>
```

Comment: tab? -> I used in this way for it should not give any error if the object is not available.
Let me remove that and let me try.